# Opengl color interpolation

Tags: python, opengl, colors, interpolation

When rendering an openGL triangle I obtain the result below [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJ2ea.jpg)

Here are my codes:

```
GL_VERT_SHADER = '''
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 vertPos; // Input position
layout (location = 1) in vec4 vertCol; // Input color
out vec4 color;
uniform mat4 finalMatrix; // The final matrix
void main() {
gl_Position = finalMatrix * vec4(vertPos.x, vertPos.y, vertPos.z, 1.0);
color = vertCol;
}
'''

GL_FRAG_SHADER = '''
#version 330
in vec4 color;
void main() {
gl_FragColor = color;
}
'''

class frame(OpenGLFrame):
    def initgl(self):
        #viewport defining
        glViewport(0,0,self.width,self.height)
        #depth test enabling (z-buffering) and stencil buffer test
        self.identity = np.array(mat4(1))
        #init program shader
        vertexshader = shaders.compileShader(GL_VERT_SHADER, GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
        fragmentshader = shaders.compileShader(GL_FRAG_SHADER, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)
        self.shaderProgram = shaders.compileProgram(vertexshader, fragmentshader)
        vao = glGenVertexArrays(1)
        self.vaosnap  = vao
        glBindVertexArray(vao)
        vbo = glGenBuffers(1)
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,vbo)
        coins = [-1,-1,0,255,0,0,1,
                 1,-1,0,0,255,0,1,
                 0,1,0,0,0,255,1]
        coins = (GLfloat * len(coins))(*coins)
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,data=coins,usage=GL_STATIC_DRAW,size=sizeof(coins))
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0)
        glVertexAttribPointer(0,3,GL_FLOAT,False,28,None)
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1)
        glVertexAttribPointer(1,4,GL_FLOAT,False,28,ctypes.c_void_p(12))
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,0)
        glBindVertexArray(0)
```

I try to understand how openGL interpolate colors in a primitive face, in order to create map coloring meshes in a FEM application

Comment: Generally, OpenGL expects colors to be set as floats in `0.0 .. 1.0` range.

Comment: Thank you. it works when I change red into 1,0,0 green into 0,1,0 and blue into 0,0,1

Answer (score -1):

Finally, I obtain a better result
[Graphic Printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/754g9.png)

However I have another question: how could I set the mapping more realistic without abrupt colors transition due to triangles edges?